# How to get Facebook to automatically publish articles when they are published on my site

Tags: facebook, integration, facebook-stream-story

I work for a tech blog and we are interested in having our stories published directly to Facebook when they are published on our site. How do I go about doing this?

For example, we publish article XXXX on our site, I want Facebook to automatically update our Facebook page with the title of that article, photo preview and link to the article. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you using Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion on the WordPress website with more information.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-updates-to-facebook-fan-page

A quick Google also revealed "Facebook Page Publish".

Personally for my blog, I have a plugin (Twitter Tools) that posts everything to Twitter, and my Twitter already posts everything to my Facebook.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. i am going to look into both this facebook plugin as well as the one for twitter!